# is graphene not inheriantly conductive?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, continuity

I ordered some graphene off ebay to test on some applications and I am unable to get continuity.

I applied a layer of graphene on some two sided tape, made sure the adhesive was completely covered, then removed the excess with cello tape.

[image: continuity]

Is there something else you're supposed do to graphene in order to get continuity response?  Or did I get fake/contaminated graphene?

Comment: seeing as graphene is just the non-bulk form of ordinary graphite (provider of fine pencil leads) and graphite is quite conductive, you should see continuity. If you don't, it probably means you don't have a continuous layer, i.e. each of the microscopic flakes might not be making good contact with its neighbor.

Comment: insulation  layer?  The graphene arrived in powered form. I added it to the tape myself.  Nobody is making conductive strips so I was creating my own.
If there is a protective coating on dust, how would I remove that?

Comment: @Sam I coated it real good.  But if you're in agreement that it should work, let me try creating a second strip and look real good for user error.  The original graphene was discovered using two pieces of cello tape. I am trying to emulate that process to make a test tail for a drone.

Comment: Do you measure anything if you poke your probes into the bulk powder?

Comment: @brhans  nothing.  I would expect to get something.  But I get nah-dah

Comment: Is your DMM working? Can you measure something else? Don't measure continuity but the resistance.

Comment: It looks like you have your DMM switched to 'Continuity'. Try it on 'Ohms' instead ...

Comment: While it *is* true that it was first discovered using tape, I think they may have used an electron microscope as opposed to a multimeter. I know that graphite powder makes a good lubricant because it traps water molecules between layers and this is what allows each flake to slide easily, I'd imagine the same with graphene. Water is not terribly conductive (especially at the nanoscale), see if you can measure anything if you test a compressed sample, I mean put some graphene in a cap and press the whole lot, then measure it, it might just need some 'persuasion' to make good contact.

Comment: @brhans I do get resistance  http://i.imgur.com/cblUosX.jpg  hmmm.  Thats the opposite of what I would expect.

Comment: Continuity checker is just detecting whether you're under a certain number of ohms. Since you have powdered graphene and not a monolayer of graphene, your resistance will be higher than what the continuity checker is looking for. Resistance measurement gives you a greater ohm-range to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphene is a conductor, but the way you have applied it there will be significant resistance.  You don't really have in any way a single layer of graphene.  You have many layers overlapping over a long range, in some places better than others.

This means your continuity checker won't go off because they are typically set for less than 1Ohm.  Rather your resistance measurement should give you somewhere between 25 and 150 Ohms.

This resistance is determined by: length of piece, thickness of graphene layer, quality of graphene layer.  Any voids in the graphene will increase the resistance, and if there is a cross section perpendicular to the length which has particularly poor connectivity, this will choke the whole piece (a 0ohm resistor in series with a 25Ohm resistor is 25 Ohms ... the 0 Ohm was "choked" by the 25Ohm).

You could try measuring in 1 inch increments along the length and plot out which parts are most resistive.

Comment: even at very close intervals I am unable to get a continuity reading. But I do get ohms which correlates with your answer.  I think you are correct, this is user error not getting a thin and complete enough sheet

Any suggestions on how to get one?

Comment: @user1544207 you get a block of graphite and pull off monolayers of graphene using the tape. Throw away your powder.

Comment: @horta whether the product is powdered or in rock form should make zero difference   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z74i-GG3vnY

Comment: I got it.  I put some on clear plastic and rubbed it in with tissue paper  http://i.imgur.com/BZ730CK.jpg  the other half of the plastic without the fine graphite powder does not conduct/register anything.  Clearly the graphene has continuity

Comment: Be careful with the powder.  It is not good to breathe.

Comment: @user1544207 Did you miss the part where he said 400 ohms per square with his sheet? That's usable for measuring signals for a touchscreen but that's horrible for trying to send any significant current. You'd have to have your probes virtually right next to eachother to get a continuity reading on it.

Comment: @horta  I have been trying to ponder/find/google a way to get the resistance down to anything usable. Copper has a resistance of .5 ohms.  Other than applications where you need resistance, I'm not 100% sure how to drive the stuff for regular applications such as carrying current on a main, without putting it on dead flat glass.

Comment: @user1544207 i'd be interested to see what you could get out of a block of graphite that you pulled a layer of graphene from. According to the literature, the resistance per cm is 10^-6 for monolayer carbon which should be good enough for carrying significant current.

Answer (score 1):

Graphene was created with tape and solid graphite, not tape and powdered graphite. I think you're confused about what graphene really is. A sheet of touching graphite particles is not graphene, rather it's a sheet of bonded molecules.

Comment: Thats why its going on a strip of tape, just like the original experiment

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OP2IXFZ.jpg

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xbWESxA.jpg

Comment: @user1544207  The original experiment started with a block of graphite, and used the tape to pull layers off of that.  Sometimes they didn't get multiple layers but a single layer.  Perhaps do a little more research on it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some definitions: graphene is a monolayer of graphite.  It is unstable, tending to fold up on itself or clump together, at which point it is no longer really graphene, rather it becomes something in-between graphene and graphite. To stop this from happening, you have to fix it to a substrate that holds it flat - and you have to do this *before* making it from graphite. So whatever you have in that bag, it is not graphene.

The original way of making true graphene was to stick some graphite onto a piece of tape, then peel the graphite off layer by layer until only one was left.  The tape would then hold it flat.  There is no advantage to putting already-folded sheets onto tape, it will not flatten them out again.

On ebay I see one seller selling "1-3 layer graphene" which sounds like the folded-up sheets. This will have similar properties to graphene, but it is not exactly the same. There several selling "graphene oxide", this is a chemical precursor from which graphene can be made, and is quite different.

Assuming you have the first one, then each individual particle will be conductive, but also only at most 0.01mm across.  So there's no way you're going to get both probes on one sheet.  Instead, if you stick the probes into a pile of it, then the resistance will be dominated by the interfaces between sheets.  The more compact it is the lower the resistance will be. If it is spread out along a piece of tape, then there will be gaps, and the resistance will be high.

Answer (score 0):

OK first off I know very little about graphene.  But it is a single layer substance.  I've seen single (small) sheets for sale with the graphene placed on a substrate.  If I had such a piece the last thing I would do is try and push 1 mA through it.  (1 mA is a guess at the current your DMM puts out in Resistance mode.)  Because I think (don't know) that that much current would wreck the device.  I'm not sure what you have with graphene powder, or how you'd get conduction from one piece to the next.  In graphite you have many many layers on top of each other.

Comment: the multimeter is in continuity mode in the posting.
I do get a measurable amount of resistance. But I fully expect continuity and not much resistance at all.